# Color Conversion from Integer to Hex?

Tags: colors, hex, data-conversion

Fun challenge, harder than you think. Given the integer `16744448` as a "color" end up with the color blue.

If you google the color, it shows right as `#0080FF`, but if you then go to a Decimal to hex converter, you get `#FF8000`.

I am not sure if one is counted as a "subtractive" color pallette, and the other is "additive", but somehow the number '16744448' which is stored in a database I am accessing relates to the color blue.

Comment: looks to me like it's the same bytes in reverse order.

Comment: True, but does that mean the renderer is reading it in reverse, or is it maybe showing it as an additive. We all know yellow and blue makes green, but that is only true in subtractive colors, using a yellow spotlight, and a blue spotlight gets you close to white in additive.

Comment: Blue should just be `#0000FF`.

Comment: But the color I posted is the right shade of blue :)

Comment: What renderer are you giving the decimal value to?

Comment: What do you mean by subtractive color pallette. You don't get `0080FF` if you subtract `FF8000` from `FFFFFF`, you get `007FFF`

Comment: This looks like an endianness issue. Your database has the number in little-endian format.

Comment: You are right, I had no idea of these other numbering systems. I found the right one here https://www.scadacore.com/tools/programming-calculators/online-hex-converter/  (UINT32 - Little Endian (DCBA))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number was stored in a database, to convert it automatically during select I used this:

```
select  REVERSE(RIGHT(INTTOHEX(16744448),6))
```